# Problem execute calculations in a nested loop. TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, loops, math

I'm trying to calculate the [sum of squared errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares) and i'm using a nested loop.

[image]

I'm new to Python and i apologize, but i encounter the error:

```
  File "...", line 13, in <module>
    for y in values_subtraction_mean:
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

The problem is with the second loop, when i have to calculate `result`  in:
   `for y in values_subtraction_mean: result = sum(math.sqrt(y))`

In the second loop, it should show all values of `values_subtraction_mean`, so it should show `2.2, -0.8, 0.2, 1.2, -2.8`. Next for each value above, a sqrt should be calculated and get `4.84, 0.64, 0.04, 1.44, 7.84`. In the end you have to sum all these numbers and get `14.8`

What am I doing wrong?

```
from numpy import mean
import math

values = [5, 2, 3, 4, 0]

mean = mean(values)

for x in values:
  values_subtraction_mean = x - mean
  print(values_subtraction_mean)
  #2.2, -0.8, 0.2, 1.2, -2.8

  for y in values_subtraction_mean:
    result = sum(math.sqrt(y))
    print(result)
    #sqrt: 4.84, 0.64, 0.04, 1.44, 7.84
    #sum and result: 14.8
```

I tried using this, but it doesn't solve the problem:

```
import numpy as np
values = np.array([5, 2, 3, 4, 0])
```

I tried not using numpy, calculating the mean with: `sum(values) / len(values)`, but it doesn't work either and i get error:

`TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Comment: I see you are doing `sum(value)`, but you do not have a variable named `value`, only a variable named `values`. Did you mean `sum(values) / len(values)`?

Comment: @A NickODell Oops, yes, you're right. It was just a typo and distraction on my part, i'll correct it now. However, even writing values, i still get the same error: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable. It was nice of you to point that out to me. Could you help me?

Comment: print out the value of `values_subtraction_mean`. it will be a single number, and you can't iterate over a single number. what do you expect `values_subtraction_mean` to be?

Comment: @jkr I expect values_subtraction_mean to be: 2.2, -0.8, 0.2, 1.2, -2.8. So every number of values from which I subtract the average (2.8)

Comment: @jkr I have updated the code showing the numbers and the result I would like to get

Comment: Show the actual error - with traceback (context).  `values` is a list, `x` is one number from that list.  What is the `y` loop supposed to do?  Why the `sum`?  That expects an iterabke.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm writing to correct translation problems. y should show all values of values_subtraction_mean, so y should show 2.2, -0.8, 0.2, 1.2, -2.8. Next for each value above, a sqrt should be calculated and get 4.84, 0.64, 0.04, 1.44, 7.84. Finally you have to add all these numbers. I updated the question, better showing the error. I hope you appreciate my changes, as i will appreciate a hypothetical help from you

Comment: `values_subtraction_mean` is just one number.  You can't iterate on it.

Comment: @hpaulj Just a number? I would like it to be: 2.2, -0.8, 0.2, 1.2, -2.8. Could you show me, if you want, an answer on how to solve the problem? Thank you

Comment: `x` is one number, the loop iteration variable.  I think you need more practice with basic python `for` loops.  And pay close attention to indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have problems understanding basic python iteration, let alone numpy.  So lets look at your code in detail

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: import math
   ...: 
   ...: values = [5, 2, 3, 4, 0]
   ...: 
   ...: mean = np.mean(values)
   ...: 
   ...: for x in values:
   ...:   values_subtraction_mean = x - mean
   ...:   print(values_subtraction_mean)
   ...: 
   ...:   for y in values_subtraction_mean:
   ...:     result = sum(math.sqrt(y))
   ...:     print(result)
   ...: 
2.2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 12
      9 values_subtraction_mean = x - mean
     10 print(values_subtraction_mean)
---> 12 for y in values_subtraction_mean:
     13   result = sum(math.sqrt(y))
     14   print(result)

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

So the error is in that `for y in values...:` line.  The `for x in values:` works because `values` is a list.  Inside that loop it calculates the `mean` (with a numpy mean function):

```
In [2]: mean
Out[2]: 2.8

In [3]: type(mean)
Out[3]: numpy.float64

In [4]: values_subtraction_mean
Out[4]: 2.2

In [5]: x
Out[5]: 5
```

You substracted the mean from one element of the list, and then tried to iterate on that value.  The `y` loop is nested inside the `x` loop.  Plus the `x` loop isn't accumulating any of those `x-mean` values.

The following line will have problems as well

```
sum(math.sqrt(y))
```

`math` functions only work on scalars, not lists or arrays.  But python `sum` requires an iterable (e.g. a list).  So I don't quite get what you intend here.

### Corrected iteration - sort of

The standard way to iterate on a list is to append the results to a list.  Changing your code:

```
In [9]: values = [5, 2, 3, 4, 0]
   ...: 
   ...: mean = np.mean(values)
   ...: values_sublist = []
   ...: for x in values:
   ...:   values_sublist.append(x - mean)
   ...: print(values_sublist)
   ...: result = []
   ...: for y in values_sublist:
   ...:     result.append(math.sqrt(y))
   ...: print(result)
[2.2, -0.7999999999999998, 0.20000000000000018, 1.2000000000000002, -2.8]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 10
      8 result = []
      9 for y in values_sublist:
---> 10     result.append(math.sqrt(y))
     11 print(result)

ValueError: math domain error
```

`values_sublist` is all the list values minus their mean.  So the `y` loop works.  But it runs into another problem - it can't take the sqrt of a negative number!

### numpy version

```
In [10]: values
Out[10]: [5, 2, 3, 4, 0]

In [11]: mean=np.mean(values)

In [12]: mean
Out[12]: 2.8

In [13]: np.array(values)-mean
Out[13]: array([ 2.2, -0.8,  0.2,  1.2, -2.8])

In [14]: np.sqrt(np.array(values)-mean)
C:\Users\14256\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8020\509743582.py:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  np.sqrt(np.array(values)-mean)
Out[14]: array([1.4832397 ,        nan, 0.4472136 , 1.09544512,        nan])
```

It's possible to do this without the python loops, if `values` is a numpy array.  Now the negative values produce a `nan` value, and a warning.  There's no point to doing the `sum` on the array with `nan`.

### complex values

We can deal with the `sqrt` issue by making values a `complex` dtype array:

```
In [15]: values_c = np.array(values,complex); values_c
Out[15]: array([5.+0.j, 2.+0.j, 3.+0.j, 4.+0.j, 0.+0.j])

In [16]: np.mean(values_c)
Out[16]: (2.8000000000000003+0j)

In [17]: values_c - np.mean(values_c)
Out[17]: array([ 2.2+0.j, -0.8+0.j,  0.2+0.j,  1.2+0.j, -2.8+0.j])

In [18]: np.sqrt(values_c - np.mean(values_c))
Out[18]: 
array([1.4832397 +0.j        , 0.        +0.89442719j,
       0.4472136 +0.j        , 1.09544512+0.j        ,
       0.        +1.67332005j])

In [19]: np.sum(_)
Out[19]: (3.0258984079294224+2.5677472440680673j)
```

Though I'm not sure that's what you need.

### square instead of sqrt

But wait, the "sqrt" values that you want are actually the square values, not square root.

```
In [20]: values = [5, 2, 3, 4, 0]
    ...: mean = np.mean(values)
    ...: values_sublist = []
    ...: for x in values:
    ...:   values_sublist.append(x - mean)
    ...: print(values_sublist)
    ...: result = []
    ...: for y in values_sublist:
    ...:     result.append(y**2)
    ...: print(result); print(sum(result))
[2.2, -0.7999999999999998, 0.20000000000000018, 1.2000000000000002, -2.8]
[4.840000000000001, 0.6399999999999997, 0.04000000000000007, 1.4400000000000004, 7.839999999999999]
14.8
```

Now your two loops work just fine.

And written as one numpy expression:

```
In [21]: np.sum((np.array(values)-np.mean(values))**2)
Out[21]: 14.8
```

We could also use a list comprehension in place of the for loops - though we still have to use `np.mean`, or a loop equivalent.  So it isn't a pure list calculation:

```
In [22]: values
Out[22]: [5, 2, 3, 4, 0]

In [23]: mean
Out[23]: 2.8

In [24]: sum((x-mean)**2 for x in values)
Out[24]: 14.8
```

That sqrt and complex code may be a distraction, but I'll leave that in because I think it may be instructive.  It's part of debugging your code.

Comment: Thank you. I voted and accepted your answer. You've been kind

Answer (score 3):

```
values = [5, 2, 3, 4, 0]

# Calculate the mean of the values
mean_value = sum(values) / len(values)

# Initialize sum of squared errors
sse = 0

# Loop through the values and calculate the squared error for each
for x in values:
    error = x - mean_value
    squared_error = error ** 2
    sse += squared_error

print(f"Sum of Squared Errors: {sse}")
```

Comment: I would like to use the loop. Instead you directly used values inside squared_errors = (values - mean_value). Could you show me an alternative solution with the loop please? (which is what I asked in the question). Thank you

Comment: values = [5, 2, 3, 4, 0]

# Calculate the mean of the values
mean_value = sum(values) / len(values)

# Initialize sum of squared errors
sse = 0

# Loop through the values and calculate the squared error for each
for x in values:
    error = x - mean_value
    squared_error = error ** 2
    sse += squared_error

print(f"Sum of Squared Errors: {sse}")

Comment: Do you mind fixing the indentation? This will create an `IndentationError`.

Comment: please check fixing the indentation

Comment: @Manoj BhosleIs there a simpler way to use sse directly as a simple variable, without using += and without initializing it with sse = 0?

Comment: @NickODell can you please share your thought in the form of code? Thanks

Comment: @ManojBhosle The indentation looks fine to me.

Comment: @ManojBhosle Thank you. I upvoted your answer. I appreciated your help

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a nested for loop rather you need 2 empty lists to store values.

Also you need to square values not square root.

```
from numpy import mean
import math

values = [5, 2, 3, 4, 0]
values_subtraction_mean =[]  # empty list to store values
result= []                   # empty list to store values

mean = mean(values)

for x in values:
    values_subtraction_mean.append(x - mean)
    
    
print(values_subtraction_mean)

for y in values_subtraction_mean:
    result.append(y**2)
print(result)

total = sum(result)
print(total)
```

---

```
#output

[2.2, -0.7999999999999998, 0.20000000000000018, 1.2000000000000002, -2.8]
[4.840000000000001, 0.6399999999999997, 0.04000000000000007, 1.4400000000000004, 7.839999999999999]
14.8
```

---

**Edit:**

Numpy version without `forloops`

```
import numpy as np
values = np.array([5, 2, 3, 4, 0])

mean_diff = values-np.mean(values)
#array([ 2.2, -0.8,  0.2,  1.2, -2.8])

sq_values = (values-np.mean(values))**2
#array([4.84, 0.64, 0.04, 1.44, 7.84])

total = sum(sq_values)
#14.8
```

Comment: 's Interesting! But is something similar possible, but without the empty list and append? This is just an example, but I will have hundreds or thousands of numbers in the list. I'd rather not use it to speed things up a little. I upvoted your answer anyway. Thank you

Comment: @Nodigap I have added the `numpy` version without `append, forloops`. This should be faster.

Comment: An empty list and list append IS the way used in python to collect values in loop.

Comment: @Goku-standswithPalestine Thank you. I upvoted your answer. I accepted hpaulj's answer because it was more elaborate and he spent more time on it, but yours would have deserved it too. I appreciated your help

Comment: You're welcome!